# Pivot table sorting pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

My initial df is:

```
  ordinal     id_easy   latitude    longitude
        1     141       45.0714     7.6187
        2     141       45.0739     7.6195
        ...
```

After applying Pivot table
my it looks like:

```
latitude                                            ...     longitude
ordinal     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  ...     1673    1674    1675    1676    1677    1678    1679    1680    1681    1682
id_easy                                                                                     
141     45.1024     45.1027     45.1072     45.1076     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
403     45.0595     45.0595     45.0564     45.0533     45.0501     45.0468     45.0432     45.0356     45.0264     45.0174     ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
920     45.0695     44.9727     44.9726     44.9566     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     ...     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Everything is almost OK, but here I have first latitude values and then longitude values. Can I do something to make it 1 by 1? for each 'id_easy' - latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) by second level:

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1, level=1)
```